# how edit a row in html grid?

Tags: jquery, html, grid

I have generated a grid with this code:

```
newcontent += "<tr><td class=\"row\">" + a[i][0] + "</td><td>" + a[i][1] + "</td><td class=\"edit\"><img class=\"editrow\" name=\"" + a[i][2] + "\" src=\"../images/1321797859_edit.png\" /><img class=\"deleterow\" name=\"" + a[i][2] + "\" src=\"../images/1321787179_edit-delete.png\" />";
```

But when I want to get a row using this jQuery code:

```
 $("img.editrow").click(function () {
      alert($("td.row").text());
 });
```

It will return all numbers of the row.

Comment: hi, it is too difficult to understand you! can you explain your problem in simple english... what are you trying? and wht problem are you facing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could happen if you have other td.row in page

try like so

```
  $("img.editrow").click(function () {
       alert($(this).closest('tr').find("td.row").text());
  });
```

Answer (score 2):

This should fit your requirements:

```
$(".editrow").click(function () {
    alert($(this).closest('tr').find('td.row').text());
});
```

See the example: http://jsfiddle.net/6PfHP/3/

Comment: Using the closest() method is the better way. I've updated my answer